# Characterization of the Picard's condition for integral equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, singularity-theory, integral-operators

Picard's condition (Thm. 15.18, Kress et al. 1989) is essential to study the existence of a solution of a Fredholm integral equation of the first kind. Specifically, consider (the univariate case) the integral equation:

$$\int_a^b K(s,t) f(t) dt = g(t)$$

with kernel $K(s,t)$, where $g(t)$ are known functions, and $f(t)$ is the unknown, sought function.

An equivalent condition of the existence of $f(t)$ is as follow: Suppose $K$ admits the singular value expansion (Thm. 15.16, Kress et al. 1989):

$$K(s,t)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_i u_i(s) v_i(t)$$

where $\{\mu_i\}$ are singular values, $\{u_i\}$, $\{v_i\}$ are orthogonal bases w.r.t. to the usual inner product $(\phi,\psi):=\int \phi(t)\psi(t)dt$, such that $\{\mu_i^2,u_i\}$ are the eigensolutions of the symmetric kernel $\int_a^b K(s,x)K(t,x)dx$ and $\{\mu_i^2,v_i\}$ are the eigensolutions of $\int_c^d K(x,s)K(x,t)dx$.

Then, the integral equation has a solution if and only if:

(1) $g\in \mathcal{N}(K^*)^{\perp}$, the orthogonal complement of the null space of the adjoint of $K$.

(2) $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\frac{(u_i,g)}{\mu_i})^2<\infty$.

**My question is**: Is there any intuitive characterization (a sufficient or necessary condition) of the abstract Picard's condition?

For example, "when the solution exists, then $K$ and $g$ satisfy ... (some intuitive conditions)".

I searched over Google scholar and found no paper on this. But I feel this like an important question, as we always hope to first check whether the solution exists before actually trying to solve the equation.

Reference:
R. Kress. Linear integral equations. 1989.